# How do I clear the terminal in VSCode programmatically?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

I would like to clear the terminal each time I run in java automatically.  Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Well if you are using OSX or Linux you would use `clear` but, if you are using Windows cmd or powsershell then you would use `cls`. While clearing it automatically, is to generic and to trigger an action like that would either require keywords to run i.e., command alias or schedule an action (task) or cron job.

Comment: i put a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/913) before and now the official replied, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you there's no such setting that can clear the terminal automatically, but we have some workarounds except running clear commands in terminal:

1. Add `"console": "externalTerminal",` in launch.json, then every time you run the java project, there will be an new terminal displayed without previous information;
   [image]
2. Install **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)** and add the following code in Settings.json:

   ```
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
   ```

[image]

Comment: I tried to change the value of "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput" to TRUE but it says "Cannot edit in read-only editor".